# Bootstrap: Toggle visibility of elements for browsers, not for print?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of elements that can contain a large number of sub-elements. 
For keeping the layout clearly arranged the `element-long` are by default invisible. When the user clicks the `Show more` entry the visibility of `element-short` and `element-long` is toggeled via JavaScript (`.children('.element-short, .element-long').toggle()`).

```
<div class="element-short" style="display: none;">
  <p>Heading</p>
  <ul> [truncated sub-element list] </ul>
  <div>Show more</div>
</div>
<div class="element-long" style="display: block;">
  <p>Heading</p>
  <ul> [full sub-element list] </ul>
</div>
```

The problem is now that this changes the visibility for both, on-screen and printing. However for printing I want that all `element-long` sections are printed and the `element-short` section are always hidden, independently if the user has clicked the show more button before or not.

Bootstrap has a lot of `visible-*-block` classes, however these classes only target a special display size and not the general visibility in the web browser.

How can I show/hide a section via JavaScript only in the web browser, but keep it always visible or hidden while printing?

Comment: Have you tried using MQ `@media print {…}`?

Comment: It's in the documentation. It would have taken less time to find than writing a question here. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-print

Comment: @Tomalak Please show me where the accepted answer is documented in the section you have linked to. Please read the full question (and understand it) before down-voting!

Comment: I have not downvoted. The accepted answer has nothing to do with the documentation link. Bootstrap already has a built-in CCS class for what you want and you really should be using this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

**CSS:**

```
@media print {
  .element-short {
    display: none !important
  }
  .element-long {
    display: block !important
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use media query

```
@media print {
  .show-me-when-print {
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen {
  .hide-me-in-screen {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

and add those class to your item

```
<div class="item hide-me-in-screen show-me-when-print">
    show me when print
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3zqetL69/